# How to add body to QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

i'm stuck ...

I create QTabWidget

```
h_mainTabAccounts = new QTabWidget(ui.centralWidget);
h_mainTabAccounts->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("h_mainTabAccounts"));
h_mainTabAccounts->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1281, 781));
h_mainTabAccounts->setElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);
h_mainTabAccounts->setMovable(false);
int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab("first",NULL);// QString::fromStdString(a.user));
```

And now, i want to add a table to this TABS (i have 3-4 TABS) , and want to add other tables to tab.

How to add widget (table - QTableWidget) , and how to fit my table to TAB BODY (of QTabWidget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And now, i want to add a table to this TABS (i have 3-4 TABS) , and
>   want to add other tables to tab.

So to have the QTableWidget be the content of your first tab, you'd change this:

```
int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab("first",NULL);// QString::fromStdString(a.user));
```

to this:

```
QTableWidget * myTableWidget = new QTableWidget;
int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab(myTableWidget, "first");
```

... and so on for whatever other tabs you wanted to add.

As far as fitting the table size to the size of your QTabWidget, that should happen automatically.

Comment: Mhm :
`h_mainTabAccounts = new QTabWidget(ui.centralWidget);
QTableWidget * myTableWidget = new QTableWidget;
int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab("First",myTableWidget);`

error `C2664: 'int QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget *,const QIcon &,const QString &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'QWidget *'`

Comment: EHh.. its okej but not `int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab("first", myTableWidget);`

This :
`int index = h_mainTabAccounts->addTab(myTableWidget,"first");`

Thanks :)